# How to get the screen size with C++ builder (Firemonkey)

Tags: c++, c++builder, firemonkey-fm3, c++builder-xe6

I know it is a stupid question, but when changing visual libraries I found a "throuble" with FMX...
My problem is: I need to do my own border, so I set the propriety to Border Style:"None", but the application runs in full screen, also covering the windows toolbar, so I would like a way to resize the application form according to the screen eg.:

```
mainForm->Height = Screen->Height - 10;
```

It is possible using VCL, but are there any way to do it using FMX library?
The maximum I conquested with FMX is (I don't know how does it returns values, and the kind of values):

```
Screen->Size(); // TSize
```

I've also conquested it now, but I have compiler error:

```
TSize* Tamanho = new TSize;
Tamanho = Screen->Size();
frmPrincipal->Width = Tamanho->Width;
frmPrincipal->Height = Tamanho->Height - 10;
```

Error:"E2034 Cannot covert 'TSize' to 'TSize*'"

Finally I've tried to put it on frmPrincipal.h, but the same error:

```
TSize *Tamanho;
```

PS.: Other possible solutions to solve the "main problem" are acceptable...

Thanks a LOT!

Comment: Have you tried searching the internet for something like "c++ builder firemonkey screen size"?

Comment: Yes, but nothing found... I've also accessed the docwiki page, but nothing that solves my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TScreen::Size()` return an actual instance of the `TSize` struct, not a `TSize*` pointer.  You need to change your code accordingly:

```
TSize Tamanho = Screen->Size();
frmPrincipal->Width = Tamanho.Width;
frmPrincipal->Height = Tamanho.Height - 10;
```

Alternatively, you can use FMX's [Platform Services](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/FireMonkey_Platform_Services) framework to access the [`IFMXScreenService`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXScreenService) interface directly (this is what `TScreen::Size()` uses internally):

```
_di_IInterface Intf;
if (TPlatformServices::Current->SupportsPlatformService(__uuidof(IFMXScreenService), Intf))
{
    _di_IFMXScreenService Svc = Intf; 
    TPoint size = Svc->GetScreenSize().Round();
    frmPrincipal->Width = size.X;
    frmPrincipal->Height = size.Y - 10;
}
```